# UNIX Socket Programming: Issues Getting a C Client to Connect to a Python Server

Tags: python, c, linux, sockets, unix

I'm trying to get a C Client to connect to a Python server in UNIX/Linux.  However, it seems my C Client isn't able to connect to the Python server.  I tried running on the localhost, but that didn't seem to work.  **Hard-coding the hostnames into both the server and the client (to "127.0.0.1") didn't work either.**

Here's the code for the Python server:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8888

print("creating socket...")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("binding socket...")
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("error binding socket, {}, {}".format(err[0], err[1]))
print("successfully bound socket")

s.listen(1)
print("now listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT))

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.sendall(str.encode("testing"))
    #conn.close()

s.close()
```

...and here's the code for the C Client:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: client [HOSTNAME] [PORT]\n");
        return 0;
    }

    const char *hostname = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);

    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;

    memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff));
    if ( sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port   = htons(port);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(hostname);

    if ( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr_in*)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not connect to %s:%i\n", hostname, port);
        return 1;
    }

    while ( n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff) - 1) > 0 ) {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if ( fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == "EOF" ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: fputs\n");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, I can still connect to the Python server via other means, like telnet, or through this client coded in Python:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8888

print("creating socket")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("attempting to connect to host")
try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("error: could not connect to host, {}, {}".format(err[0], err[1]))
    sys.exit()

print("successfully connected to host")

data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()

print("The server responded with: {}".format(data))
```

I assume this is a client-side issue, then, since other methods to connecting to the server seems to work just fine.  If that is the case, how would I go about fixing the C Code to connect properly?  If that is not the case, could this be an issue pertaining to my network?  I tried running in both an Arch VM and my school's IT Servers, and both yielded the same result.

Comment: What *does* happen when your C client "doesn't work"?

Comment: Have you tried running your client in a debugger to see what it's doing?

Comment: The C Client fails to connect.  It stops at "error: could not connect to [host]", and simply exits.  I assume this means the client simply failed to connect to the server.  And no, I haven't run the client in a debugger as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your C client incorrectly sets the address to (try to) connect to.  In fact, given that variable `hostname` is a `char *` pointing to one of the program arguments, this is completely wrong:

```
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(hostname);
```

Your compiler should be emitting warnings about it; if not, then either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.  `htonl()` expects a 32-bit unsigned integer as its argument.  A pointer can be converted to that type (though not without a cast, except as an extension), but that converts *the pointer itself*, not the data to which it points.

You need to convert the provided string-form address to numeric form, and assign *that* to your socket address.  Provided that you are willing to rely on the "hostname" to in fact be formatted as a dotted-quad IPv4 address, you can instead do this:

```
int result = inet_pton(AF_INET, hostname, &saddr.sin_addr);
```

Do not neglect to check the return value, and be aware that it employs an unusual convention: you're looking for it to return 1 (not 0) if the conversion is successful.

If you want to accept domain names as well as dotted-quad addresses then you will need to engage the resolver to help you choose an appropriate destination address based on the program argument.  The [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) function is your best entry there, but *do* carefully read the (linked) docs, as there are some potential gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the manual of `htonl` it will say `htonl(uint32_t hostlong);`.

You're passing as argument a string, hoping that it's converted to the correct `uint32` format. That's not going to happen.

You can use for example

```
hostinfo = gethostbyname (hostname);
saddr->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *) hostinfo->h_addr;
```

Comment: +1 for an accurate answer, but do take note of these leading comments from the Linux manual page of `gethostbyname()`: "The `gethostbyname*`() and `gethostbyaddr*`() functions are obsolete.  Applications should use `getaddrinfo`(3) and `getnameinfo`(3) instead."